# Bound of eigenvalues of product of two positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose I have two positive definite matrices A and B, 
Eigenvalues of A are bounded between u, v
Eigenvalues of B are bounded between s, t
All real numbers u,v,s,t are in range [0, 1].

I can infer that their multiplication (AB) is also positive definite, and also infer a bound on the eigenvalues of AB?

Thanks

Comment: You should find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113842/81360) or [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/314823/81360) to be useful.

Can you clarify which definition of "positive definite" you're using? For instance, are positive definite matrices necessarily symmetric?